# Segmentation Fault - Displaying Tree

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I get a segfault when calling viewTree(root);

```
    struct treeElement {
        unsigned long weight;
        unsigned short id;
        char chr;
        struct treeElement *lchild, *rchild, *parent;
    };

    typedef struct treeElement node;

    node *root;

    //INITIALIZE TREE
    void initTree() {
        root = malloc(sizeof(node));
        currentNYT = root;
    } //initTree

    //VIEW TREE
    void viewTree(node *tree) {
        printf("%5d%5d%5d%5d%5c%lu", tree->id, tree->parent->id, tree->lchild->id, tree->rchild->id, tree->chr, tree->weight);
        viewTree(tree->lchild);
        viewTree(tree->rchild);
    }

//ADD NODE
void addNode(char newNodeChr) {
    node *newNYT, *newExternal;
    newNYT = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNYT->id=maxNodes-idCount; idCount++;
    newNYT->chr='\0';
    newNYT->weight=0;
    newNYT->parent=currentNYT;
    newNYT->lchild=newNYT->rchild=NULL;
    newExternal = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newExternal->id=maxNodes-idCount;
    newExternal->chr=newNodeChr;
    newExternal->weight=1;
    newExternal->parent=currentNYT;
    newExternal->lchild=newExternal->rchild=NULL;
    currentNYT->lchild = newNYT;
    currentNYT->rchild = newExternal;
    currentNYT=newNYT;
} //addNode

int main()
{
    initTree();
    addNode('a');
    addNode('b');
    viewTree(root);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the root node have a parent? Do the child leaf nodes have left and right children?

I think most of your problem lies in your `printf` statement - you don't check whether or not any of the objects you're accessing actually exist before you try to print their `id`s. Add some `if` statements in there and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewTree(node *tree)` you are not checking if `tree` is `null` or not. Definite recipe for segfault when you try to access `tree->id` when `tree` is `null`.

`null` will be passed for a subtree in a recursive call eventually.

EDIT: In general you have check for `null` every time you need to access a member of an object. So, `tree != null` before reading `tree->id` and `tree->lchild != null` before reading `tree->lchild->id` must be ensured.

Comment: Also as answered by Tim, even if tree argument is NOT NULL, you still need to check parent, child, links for NULL before using them.  +1 to both answers.

Comment: Yeah that too, before accessing deeper items.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just allocate the root node, but initialize it, especially the pointers to siblings and to parent (set them to NULL). You are using the uninitialized pointers when adding nodes.